# How to handle concurrency with django queryset get method?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

I'm using django (1.5 with mysql) select_for_update method for fetching data from one model and serve this data to user upon request, but when two user request at simultaneously it returns same data for both of the user, see the sample code below

```
models.py
class SaveAccessCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class AccessCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='OPEN')


views.py
def view(request, code):
    # for example code = 234567
    acccess_code = AccessCode.objects.select_for_update().filter(
    code=code, state='OPEN')

    acccess_code.delete()
    SaveAccessCode.objects.create(code=code)
    return
```

Concurrent request will generate two records of SaveAccessCode with same code, Please guide me how to handle this scenario in better way

Comment: Why wouldn't it serve the same data for both users? Why don't you want it to, and what should it do instead? And how are you calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some flag on the model when doing `select_for_update`, something like:

```
qs.first().update(is_locked=True)`
```

and before that should do select like

```
qs = self.select_for_update().filter(state='OPEN', is_locked=False).order_by('id')
```

Then after the user, I presume, has done something with it and saved, set the flag `is_locked=False` and save.

Also make the `fetch_available_code` as a `@staticmethod`.